# How can I control the hourly GROUPBY setting in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have the following data set:

```
time                    value
2019-01-01 8:00:00       10
2019-01-01 8:30:00       20
2019-01-01 9:00:00       30
2019-01-01 9:30:00       100
2019-01-01 10:00:00      400
```

By using the `pd.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'time', freq = '1h')).sum().reset_index()`. It returned:

```
time                   value
2019-01-01 8:00:00      30
2019-01-01 9:00:00      130
2019-01-01 10:00:00     400
```

It based on any related the Hour value to have a group aggregation. But How can I control the group time setting? Since I would like to make any `>8 to <= 9` as `9` group. For example:

```
time                   value
2019-01-01 8:00:00      10
2019-01-01 9:00:00      50
2019-01-01 10:00:00     500
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `ceil`

```
Yourdf=df.groupby(df.index.ceil('H')).sum()
                     value
time                      
2019-01-01 08:00:00     10
2019-01-01 09:00:00     50
2019-01-01 10:00:00    500
```

Or `resample`

```
df.resample('H',closed='right').sum()
                     value
time                      
2019-01-01 07:00:00     10
2019-01-01 08:00:00     50
2019-01-01 09:00:00    500
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closed='right'` i.e.

```
pd.Grouper(key = 'time', freq = '1h', closed='right')
```